# fuelphpのapcキャッシュ使ったときに、APC returned failed to write. Check your configuration.というエラーが出る

Tags: php, fuelphp

こんばんわ。
私はwebサービスを運営しているのですが、fuelphpをwebのフレームワークとして使っておりまして、fuelphpのキャッシュを使っているときに、以下のようなエラー文言が出てしまいました。

```
APC returned failed to write. Check your configuration.
```

apcキャッシュの溢れだと思い、試しに開発環境で明示的に大量のapcキャッシュを積んでみたところ、メモリーリークしたときにみる以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
Error::shutdown_handler => Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 184328 bytes)
```

なので、問題のエラー文言はメモリーリークとは違うと思いました。
問題のエラーについてどなたか分かるかたはいらっしゃいますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

APCの空き容量がない場合や
リクエストが多い時に同時書き込みや書き込みと削除が同時に起きた時などに出たことがあります
あとは、apacheかphpののエラーログにも何らかのメッセージが入ってるかもしれません